# How to restrict HTTP OPTIONS method on port 61614 in activemq?

Tags: security, jetty, activemq-classic, embedded-jetty, http-method

We are using activemq 5.14 in our application and the recent Internal Vulnerability Assessment shows that http-options-method-enabled on port 61614.

Below is the entry from activemq.xml.

```
<transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
```

```
curl "http://XX.xX.xxx.xxx:61614/" -X OPTIONS -v
* About to connect() to XX.xX.xxx.xxx port 61614 (#0)
*   Trying XX.xX.xxx.xxx... connected
* Connected to XX.xX.xxx.xxx (XX.xX.xxx.xxx) port 61614 (#0)
> OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: XX.xX.xxx.xxx:61614
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Thu, 11 Apr 2019 02:02:48 GMT
< Allow: GET, HEAD, TRACE, OPTIONS
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(9.2.13.v20150730)
<
* Connection #0 to host XX.xX.xxx.xxx left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

I have researched on this and found that active mq uses emdedded jetty and tried adding the security constraint in jetty.xml as below.

```
<bean id="httpMethodSecurityConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
        <property name="name" value="Restricted" />
         <!--<property name="roles" value="admin" /> -->
         <!-- set authenticate=false to disable login -->
        <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="httpMethodSecurityConstraintMapping" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
        <property name="constraint" ref="httpMethodSecurityConstraint" />
    <property name="method" value="OPTIONS" />
        <property name="pathSpec" value="/*" />
    </bean>

 <bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
        <property name="loginService" ref="securityLoginService" />
        <property name="authenticator">
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
        </property>
        <property name="constraintMappings">
            <list>

        <ref bean="httpMethodSecurityConstraintMapping" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="handler" ref="secHandlerCollection" />
    </bean>
```

But, the result of the below still returns http status 200.

curl "http://XX.xX.xxx.xxx:61614/" -X OPTIONS -v

Any help with this issue, would be of great help.

Thank You.

Comment: How are you deploying activemq?  do you have a war file?  are you deploying via the jetty deployment manager (aka putting content in the `${jetty.base}/webapps` directory)?

Comment: we have just downloaded the active mq zip file (http://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) and extracted it. The zip file has embedde jetty (lib/web/jetty-all-9.2.26.v20180806.jar) and there are also some jetty related config files (conf/jetty.xml).

Comment: anyone able to advise? Appreciate any help in giving pointers to fix this issue.